# Can I set up a RDS instance that replicates from multiple other RDS master instances?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Say I have three RDS instances A, B, C, each have one schema on them. I like to make an A.b schema that is a replication slave of the main schema on instance B. Then an A.c schema that is a replication slave of the main schema on instance C. Is this do-able within RDS?

Reality is that my application database is the main instance on A, then I have two other type of applications on instances B and C. During ETL to data warehouse, I need to join some tables among the three.

Although I am not on RDS/MySQL right now, I really like to. But I don't know if I can do something like I said above.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if you're asking... can I replicate instance A onto instance B even though instance B is hosting a separate application, the answer is no - at least, not if you want RDS to manage the replication for you. There might be other ways to achieve what you want to do though, but I don't think there's enough information in your question to properly help yet.

Comment: I think I get the gist of your answer. What I was hoping for is to use Replication to replicate individual database/schema from multiple instances to a common host, which in my use case, would be an ETL processor. For example, I have a database called "catalog" on host1, another database called "customer" on host2 and yet another "inventory" on host3. They are all live database to support Web App. Instead of querying them directly, I was hoping I can replicate each database (aka schema) to a central host (say host4). Hope that makes sense

Comment: Right, in that case, no, RDS managed replication will only replicate an entire instance, not on a per-database/scheme basis. However... have a look at Database Migration Service (DMS). I haven’t used it but it’s replication _may_ do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using postgres that allows you to create multiple schema. I dont think its possible with mysql